# Data doesn't get stored in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, phonegap, web-sql

I am trying to get data from WebSQL then put into an array called storeArr.  However, each time I debug, the length of the array is 0. I have failed to detect what is wrong in this code.

```
    if(button == 1){
       var compare =  a + b + d + e + f + g;
       var storeArr = [];
       var duplicate =  "";
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
              tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM RentalZ_', [], function (tx, sqlResultSet) {
              var len = sqlResultSet.rows.length;
              for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
              var data = sqlResultSet.rows.item(i);
               storeArr.push(data.property_type + data.rooms + data.rent + data.furniture + data.notes + data.name);

                    }
                }, null);
        });
        console.log(storeArr.length);
       for(i = 0; i < storeArr.length; i++){
            if(storeArr[i] == compare){
                duplicate = "YES";
                break;
            }
       }

       if(duplicate != "YES"){
            console.log("Data Successfully Added!");
            alert("added");
            db.transaction(function (tx) {
              tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO RentalZ_ (property_type, rooms, date_time, rent, furniture, notes, name) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]);
            });
       } else {
       alert("nan");
            console.log("Duplicate Data Detected!");
       }
    }
```

Comment: And, console log says?

Comment: 'console.log("Data Successfully Added!");' This is executed even if the duplicate data is found. @proofzy

Comment: Set variable duplicate to integer, 1 or 0 and control it